# AngularDart Routing - Does AngularDart support named router outlets like Angular 5

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, dart-html, dart-webui

I have used named router-outlets in angular 5, which have really worked well for me. I could tell each route where the component should render on the DOM. The key to what I am wanting to do is having the ability to tell each route exactly where to render a component.

An example would be:

```
<div class="columns">
  <md-card>
   <router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
  </md-card>
  <md-card>
   <router-outlet name="bio"></router-outlet>
  </md-card>
 </div>
```

Basically what is found here: http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

I have searched and searched and have yet to find an answer as to how to implement something like this in AngularDart. I am currently using angular_router: 1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

There was some support in earlier versions but as far as I know it never worked properly.

The new router (2.0.0-alpha.5) currently has no support at all for named outlets.